# What PyCharm run configuration does and what makes it different from just run?

Tags: python, pycharm

I just started using python and pycharm. I'm a bit confused of what is the *run configuration* in pycharm do and what is the different between the just *run* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A run configuration (not just in PyCharm, for example JetBrains IntelliJ also has them, in fact most IDEs have this concept) is a compilaton of settings to be used when running a program.

Let us stay with Python for the sake of simplicity. You might think that when you execute your script by typing in your command prompt...

```
python myscript.py
```

...that there are no settings or configuration involved. You are just running your script, right?

Not quite, you are in fact using what you could call an *implicit run configuration*, i.e. are whatever defaults and environment settings happen to take effect.

Some examples you will also find in PyCharm Python run configurations:

**Script path** is just the script you are calling, in the example `myscript.py` since we specified that on the command line.

**Python interpreter** is whatever Python interpreter is first in your path.

**Parameters** is empty in our example, as we didn't specify any on the command line.

**Working directory** is the current directory, where we are with our command prompt.

**Enviromnent variables** are those that happen to be set in our shell.

All of these and more can be defined in a run configuration (or multiple different run configurations if you need) for your project.

You can then select these conveniently from the dropdown menu, and the one currently selected will be used to execute your program when you press the green `play` button.

**What is the difference between using a `run configuration` and just `run` in PyCharm?**

If you just `run` your program, you are telling PyCharm that it should just use the project default configuration for the specific file type.

In other words, you are using a run configuration as well there, just the unmodified default configuration.